# Find if two strings are anagrams

Tags: string, algorithm

Faced this question in an interview, which basically stated

> Find if the given two strings are anagrams of each other in `O(N)` time without any extra space

I tried the usual solutions:

1. Using a character frequency count (`O(N)` time, `O(26)` space) (as a variation, iterating 26 times to calculate frequency of each character as well)
2. Sorting both strings and comparing (`O(NlogN)` time, constant space)

But the interviewer wanted a "better" approach. At the extreme end of the interview, he hinted at "XOR" for the question. Not sure how that works, since `"aa" XOR "bb"` should also be zero without being anagrams.

Long story short, are the given constraints possible? If so, what would be the algorithm?

Comment: They are anagrams if the character counts are the same, right?  No need to sort.

Comment: @Wyck: if, but not ony if.

Comment: @Wyck: Character frequency and sorting + string comparison are two alternative approaches.

Comment: For the 'without any extra space' constraint, does this allow modifying the input strings (if they are stored as character arrays)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if two words are anagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045640/how-to-check-if-two-words-are-anagrams)

Comment: This looks like an interviewer being enamoured with a cool xor solution, even if it's wrong. A quick web search brings up [this](https://pragmaticdevs.wordpress.com/2015/12/27/finding-if-two-strings-are-anagrams-or-not-using-xor/) prettily typeset article and [this](https://www.javainterviewpoint.com/anagram-program-in-java/) article about six ways to test anagrams even walks through the code in minute detail. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50475317/resolving-equal-xor-values-for-different-strings-for-anagram-detection) SO answer has more on why xor is only a necessary condition.

Comment: There's also the non-XOR solution where you associate letters with the first 26 primes (a <-> 2, b <-> 3, ...) and take the product for each string. It's hard to see how this is any more space efficient, if the hashmap of frequencies solution wasn't good enough.

Comment: If it's given there's no duplicate letters in either of the words, xor works.

Comment: @PaulHankin I'm not sure that's true, at least for the naive XOR solution. For example, (7 XOR 3) = (5 XOR 1) = 4, and there are no duplicates. Also, if there are no duplicates, and since it appears all characters are lowercase letters, then the strings have length at most 26.

Comment: @MOehm "an interviewer being enamored with a cool xor solution, even if it's wrong." --> sad, but very likely true.  Makes for a good interview quandry: How to handle an interviewer with an objectively  wrong understanding?  Likely a good (or dupe) question for another SE site.

Comment: I am reminded of a group of mathematicians who, after attending a lecture given by a famous mathematician who presented a proof of the validity of a long-standing conjecture, agree with each other that the proof was trivial.

Comment: @kcsquared sorry, I wasn't clear what I thought the xor solution was, which was xor-ring 1<<c for all the characters in both words. Equivalent to counting characters mod 2.

Comment: @chux: To be fair, we don't know whether the interviewer's intention was to provoke that quandary: Nudge the candidate into providing an "even better" solution, which is what a customer might do, and then let them realize the mistake and see how they handle the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Given `word_a` and `word_b` in the same length, I would try the following:

1. Define a variable `counter` and initialise the value to `0`.
2. For each letter `ii` in the alphabet do the following:

   2.1. for `jj` in length(`word_a`):

   2.1.1. if `word_a[jj] == ii` increase counter by 1: `counter += 1`

   2.1.2. if `word_b[jj] == ii` decrease the counter by 1: `counter -= 1`

   2.2. if after passing all the characters in the words, `counter` is different than 0, you have a different number of `ii` characters in each word and in particular they are not anagrams, break out of the loop and return `False`
3. Return True

### Explanation

In case the words are anagrams, you have the same number of each of the characters, therefore the use of the histogram makes sense, but histograms require space. Using this method, you run over the `n` characters of the words exactly `26` times in the case of the English alphabet or any other constant `c` representing the number of letters in the alphabet. Therefor, the runtime of the process is `O(c*n) = O(n)` since `c` is constant and you do not use any other space besides the one variable

Comment: This approach is correct, I had tried it as well. Forgot to mention it in the question, didn't sit well with the interviewer anyways

Answer (score -1):

I haven't proven to myself that this is infallible yet, but it's a possible solution.

Go through both strings and calculate 3 values: the sum, the accumulated xor, and the count. If all 3 are equal then the strings should be anagrams.

Comment: More like "....  then the strings could be anagrams."

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica no, I meant what I said - I haven't yet imagined a case where those values are equal but the strings aren't anagrams. I would welcome being proven wrong.

Comment: Consider "03" and "12"

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thanks, exactly the counter-example I was looking for.